# Koma Script header-footer on chapter start page

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, chapters

The `scrbook` class omits the header footer on the page where a new chapter starts. How to add them on those pages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can redefine the macro `\chapterpagestyle`, such as

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{headings}
```

Or use any page style you like. I strongly recommend not to use a headings style on chapter starting pages. While static entries are no problem, automatic running headings could be a problem. Furthermore, I don't like a header line on chapter starting pages above the chapter header.

Comment: yes it looks ugly all of a sudden

Comment: @umar: Questions with answers can't be deleted directly. You might just accept Stefan's answer. Other people might want to know the same thing and find the layout less displeasing.