# Modify chapter command (and KOMA-script addchap)

Tags: macros, sectioning, header-footer, chapters, etoolbox

Is there something like `etoolbox`'s `\appto`, that also works for `\chapter` and `\addchap`?

edit: I intend to use it to re-enable page numbering (which may or may not be disabled using `\renewcommand\thepage{}`) after each chapter's first page, but if page numbering is already enabled the chapter's first page should also be numbered.

edit2: I am tryng to create a command, that disables page numbering until next chapter, including the first page of next chapter. I was going to do this by using `\renewcommand\thepage{}` at first and adding some code to `\chapter` that checks if page numbering has been disabled (using a toggle) and if it is sets chapter's first page's style to `plain` and re-enables page numbering.

Comment: This is a very general question. Perhaps tell more about what you are trying to achieve, if you don't look just for a general answer.

Comment: In response to your edited question: Normally, there shouldn't be a need to "re-enable"  page numbering -- removing the page number from a chapter's first page is done by properly choosing and customizing a page style (normally `plain`) for these pages.

Comment: Some chapters need to have number on their first page and some do not, depending on previous pages.

Comment: In this case, some chapters need a different page style than others.

Comment: How can I define pagestyle for next chapter before the chapter itself?

Comment: You could issue `\thispagestyle{empty}` immediately *after* `\chapter`. Again, please describe what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\appto` only works for macros without any parameters. Try `\apptocmd` (or `\pretocmd` or `\patchcmd`) instead. See section 3.4 of the `etoolbox` documentation for the syntax of these commands and other details.

EDIT: Here's a MWE that removes `\clearpage` from the definition of `\chapter`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\clearpage}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\chapter{foo}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

EDIT 2: In response to your second edit: It's a somewhat strange requirement, but here we go:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{emptystyle}
\newcommand*{\emptystyleuntilnextchapter}{%
  \pagestyle{empty}%
  \booltrue{emptystyle}%
}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{%
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
}{%
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \ifbool{emptystyle}{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \pagestyle{headings}%
    \boolfalse{emptystyle}%
  }{%
  }%
}{}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\blindtext[12]

\emptystyleuntilnextchapter

\blindtext[6]

\chapter{bar}

\blindtext[6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The following seems to work: `\patchcmd{\addchap}{\clearpage}{\clearpage\foo}{}{}` and `\patchcmd{\chapter}{\clearpage}{\clearpage\foo}{}{}`

Comment: Sadly this only works for some commands - I can insert text or `\LaTeX`, but `thispagestyle{empty}` has no effect.

Comment: That might be because `\chapter` itself calls `\thispagestyle{plain}` at a later point. As I answered your original question, I suggest you ask a new one and explain exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: It probably is so. I looked up declaration of `\addchap` in `scrreprt.cls` and found the latest possible place to insert my code. Result:`\patchcmd{\chapter}{\secdef}{\foo\secdef}{}{}` works for page style too. `patchcmd` is powerful.

Comment: I did :-) btw. perhaps [`\chapterpagestyle`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18355/koma-script-header-footer-on-chapter-start-page/18356#18356) could be used also, as the question seems to deal with a KOMA-Script class.

Comment: @Stefan: Let's just say the question .. evolved.